# htaccess redirect http to https causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have edited my .htaccess file to redirect any http request to https://mydomain.se however, this has cause the website to fall in redirect loop. I have looked at the other solutions and compared them however I detected nothing wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If it does help, domain is bitech.se

Answer (score 1):

Your `RewriteCond` seems to always match, as the HTTPS version redirects back to the HTTPS over and over.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

Comment: Now it says Moved Permanently. The document has moved here. here refers to "https:///" why???

Comment: You're trying to redirect to `https:///` which doesn't actually contain a hostname. Perhaps you should actually use the hostname, instead of `%2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following settings to redirect every HTTP traffic to HTTPS with the exact requested path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```